# knockoutjs custum bindings preprocess method & addBindingCallback?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

From knockout documentation :

> **`ko.bindingHandlers.<name>.preprocess(value, name, addBindingCallback)`**
>
> *Parameters*:
>
> **value**: ...
> **name**: ...
> **addBinding**: a callback function you can optionally use to insert another binding on the current element. This requires two parameters, name and value. For example, inside your preprocess function, call `addBinding('visible', 'acceptsTerms()');` to make Knockout behave as if the element had a `visible: acceptsTerms()` binding on it.

For example we can have bindings like :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.live = {
   preprocess: function (str, name, addBindingCallback) {
      addBindingCallback('value', str);
      addBindingCallback('valueUpdate', "'afterkeydown'")
   }
};
// Or
ko.bindingHandlers.log = {
   preprocess: function (str, name, addBindingCallback) {
      addBindingCallback('click', "function(){console.log('test');}");
   }
};
```

**My Question:**
Is it possible to pass a variable within the scope of `preporcess` method to the newly added bindings ?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.log = {
   preprocess: function (str, name, addBindingCallback) {
      // an object which is not in my viewmodel and context
      var $scoped_obj = get_from_some_external_service(str);
      // i want to pass `$scoped_obj` to the newly added click binding
      addBindingCallback('click', "function(){console.log($scoped_obj);}");
   }
};
```

Is that possible ? and How ?

Comment: I don't think that should be something you should strive to do, at least within the preprocess call. What happens in the `preprocess` call should be something you'd be comfortable adding directly into your view IMHO. If you're doing calculations, those calculations should be done through the view model or otherwise done directly in the binding handler itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're trying it now, you can't, because the click handler is evaluated by a `Function`, which accepts a string as the function body. The scope is lost at that point.

What you could do is create a static function which you call inside the click handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.log = {
    functions: [],
    preprocess: function (str, name, addBindingCallback) {
        var fnIndex = ko.bindingHandlers.log.functions.length;

        var $scoped_obj = {a: 'b'};
        ko.bindingHandlers.log.functions.push(function() {
            console.log($scoped_obj);
        });
        addBindingCallback('click', "ko.bindingHandlers.log.functions["+fnIndex+"]");
   }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fpoeeb7L/

Alternatively you could use `ko.toJSON` to create the variable inside the click handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.log = {
    preprocess: function (str, name, addBindingCallback) {
        var $scoped_obj = {a: 'b'};
        addBindingCallback('click', "function() { var $scoped_obj = " + ko.toJSON($scoped_obj) + "; console.log($scoped_obj); }");
   }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5e5jbuum/

But this won't work if `$scoped_obj` contains functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-executing function to create a closure for the scoped variable. Use the closure to create the scoped variable and the function that uses it, and return the function, like so:

```
preprocess: (function() {
    var $scoped_obj = get_from_some_external_service(str);
    var fn = function(str, name, addBindingCallback) {
       // can use the scoped variable
    }; 
    return fn;
})();  // self-execution
```

However, take into account Jeff Mercado's comment to your question.